# Modify product template

Tags: tvml, tvjs

I have used the product template for my Apple Tv application, where i remove the infoList tag for remove the place in left side which is working perfectly in simulator and as well as apple tv.

- My first question is, will be there any issue or application may got rejected at verification time for this reason ?
- How to make a div template. Tags like img , description etc. not supported by div template . For showing an image in div template i had to use heroImg tag .But in documentation nothing mention like this . What to use or what to not .

Please anybody suggest what to work with div template and product template query .

Thanks in advance .